# What is the ruby test tool called that 'breaks' your code to see how tight your tests are?

Tags: ruby, testing, mutation-testing

A wee while ago I ended up on a page which hosted several ruby tools, which had 'crazy' names like 'mangler' or 'executor' or something. The tool's job was to modify you production code (at runtime) in order to prove that your tests were precise.

Unfortunately I would now like to find that tool again, but can't remember what it was called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you're thinking of the Flay project and related modules:

http://ruby.sadi.st/Ruby_Sadist.html

Answer (score 9):

I think you're thinking about Heckle, which flips your code to make sure your tests are accurate. Here:

http://seattlerb.rubyforge.org/heckle/

Comment: Sounds like heckle is what you're looking for. Also metric_fu is pretty slick for code quality metrics: http://metric-fu.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try my [mutant](https://github.com/mbj/mutant). Its AST based and currently runs under MRI and RBX in > 2.0 mode. It only has a killer for rspec3, but others are possible also.